# Entity Framework connection string: SQLCe file location

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've specified the following entry in my app.config

```
<add name="DefaultStoreConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=DefaultStore.sdf" />
```

Whenever I start my program and access the database, the database gets created at the following location

```
MyAppDir/DefaultStore.sdf
```

However, when I work with the Package Manager Console in order to create migrations, it creates the database there:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\DefaultStore.sdf
```

The file name is right, so I guess Entity Framework just takes a relative path from the calling application, in case of the Package Manager Console: Visual Studio. Can I specificy my application directory inside app.config?

Comment: is it a winforms project?

Comment: "app.config" is in a console project, database context in an external library

Comment: Have you tried `Data source=|DataDirectory|DefaulstStore.sdf;` ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

set your connection like this:

```
<add name="DefaultStoreConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DefaultStore.sdf" />
```

now you  can define the meaning of `|DataDirectory|` like this inside your `main` function (of program.cs) make sure it executes before any kind of database interaction :

```
string fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", fileName);
```

here in the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum, you get to choose the executing directory as well, you can provide your custom directory aswell.